# SQL Server Group by with filter

Tags: sql-server, grouping, sql-server-2016

I have the following requirements for querying a data:

I want to find the time difference between the last and first event in a group if there is **complete** event in a group.

```
ID  Time                Events
---------------------------------------
1   11/08/2013 00:06:51 cancel
1   11/08/2013 00:06:51 ans
1   11/08/2013 00:06:38 notification
1   11/08/2013 00:06:38 call
1   11/08/2013 00:06:38 notification
1   11/08/2013 00:06:38 active
2   11/08/2013 00:06:30 free
2   11/08/2013 00:06:30 **complete**
2   11/08/2013 00:06:13 call
2   11/08/2013 00:06:13 notification
2   11/08/2013 00:06:13 notification
2   11/08/2013 00:06:13 active
```

Please help me with the SQL query for this.

Comment: Some questions: (1) What does your expected output look like? (2) What sort of time difference are you looking for? The difference in minutes? seconds? Since `ID=2` is the only group with a complete event, it seems you'd only be expecting 1 result returned. Is this correct?

Comment: You wrote _if the complete event in group_. What determines of an event is complete?

Comment: @Zack - This is just a dummy data.And based on it Yes the query should return only one row. Time Difference can be anything in terms of format. But my question is related to taking only those groups into consideration which have a certain event (complete is my example) in those.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT id, datediff(minute, min(time), max(time)) as timediff
FROM eventtable
WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM eventtable WHERE Events = 'complete')
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I believe you need a `GROUP BY` to get the data OP is looking for.

Comment: Thank you @Zack I've added it. Shame on my for missing that one. Totally would have errored out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question (subject to revision based on your clarification), it's pretty straightforward to get what you want: First, you want any items where the `Events` field contains "complete". It seems this field is text, so you'll likely need to use the `LIKE` operator to get the records you want:

```
select *
from Items
where upper(Events) like '%COMPLETE%'
```

But it seems like you want the time difference between the first and last item in the group **regardless** of event text. So you can self-join the table to get all the items, and then get the min and max times for that item, grouping by ID. For example, take a look at the following (I've taken the liberty of redefining your table to `Events`, and renaming the columns to `EventID`, `EventTime`, and `EventText`:

```
select
    CompleteEvents.EventID
    ,min(AllEvents.EventTime) first_event
    ,max(AllEvents.EventTime) last_event
    ,datediff(s, min(AllEvents.EventTime), max(AllEvents.EventTime)) seconds_difference
from Events CompleteEvents
    inner join Events AllEvents on
        AllEvents.EventID = CompleteEvents.EventID
where 
    upper(CompleteEvents.EventText) like '%COMPLETE%'
group by CompleteEvents.EventID
```

Take a look at [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd233/8/0) for the same query.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this as:

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF(seconds, MIN(time), MAX(time)) as num_seconds
FROM eventtable
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN e.event = 'complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```